# python-docx: Remove bibliography (w:sdt) section

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-word, python-docx

My end goal here is to find and remove any bibliography section from a Microsoft Word document.

As mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/155).
There currently isn't any API support for `w:sdt` tags (which I think is only for bibliographies). However, in response to this issue, a work-around was given of:

```py
paragraph = ... # however you get the paragraph, maybe with `for paragraph in document.paragraphs`
p = paragraph._element
sdts = p.xpath('w:sdt')
for sdt in sdts:
    parent = sdt.getparent()
    parent.remove(sdt)
```

When using the above, the document's xml updates and deletes the `w:sdt` tags as I want it to. However, when I save the new document the output .docx file still includes the bibliography section.

Why is it that despite the python-docx document's xml not including the `w:sdt` elements does this not reflect once the document is saved and opened in Microsoft Word. I have read [here](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/33) that document relationships could have something to do this with but given that I get no error when opening the new word document, I don't think this is the problem. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

*Note: I am asking this question here as the [python-docx GitHub](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx) hasn't had much activity recently.*

Comment: some notes that may help you (I don't know how to use the python-docx library to detect the right thing to delete but you may). 1. w:set elements can be used for several things, not just Bibliographies, but also Citations and the various types of Content Control. 2. w:sdt elements are not necessarily contained in Paragraph elements. In fact, if you add a Bibliography in an empty paragraph in Word, the set tag won't be contained in a w:p tag . I don't know if it ever can be.

Comment: 3. A Bibliography usually consists of 2 set elements, one nested inside the other. The inner one should contain a <w:bibliography> element. (Not sure what you will see if you insert an old-fashioned { BIBLIOGRAPHY } field manually - I haven't checked.). But as long as a Bibliography is *always* constructed that way, if you can work out how to find w:bibliography elements/tags, then find the enclosing set tag and the set tag enclosing that, you should be able to make this work.

Comment: 4. The sdt tags are described in the ISO 29500 Part 1 standards document (Fundamentals and Markup Language Reference) around section 17.5.2 Microsoft have their own standards documents that document deviations from the ISO standards. 5. Your document will have a "Bibliography" Part, and that will be described in a Relationship when you remove the actual Bibliography you do not also have to remove the Bibliography Part.

Comment: Thanks for the response, from looking at my test docx xml, I can see that the sdt tags aren't a child of any p tag, yet despite this, the original code included does extract the sdt tags. Also, my test docx doesn't include any w:bibilography tag - the one in question was made using Word's default bibliography functionality.

Comment: That's interesting - my test was also using a Bibliography inserted by Word, specifically (in Windows desktop Word) using the Ribbon option Citations & Bibliography->Bibliography dropdown, choosing the built-in "Bibliography" entry. It's the same on Mac Word. There's a <w:bibliography/> element in both. So maybe we are doing things differently. If instead *just* insert a { BIBLIOGRAPHY } field, there is no SDT structure, no <w:bibliography/> element, just a regular complex field structure with field text, field result etc.

Comment: TBH it is difficult to see how removal of the SDT does not result in removal of the bibliography unless the bibliography is not actually in an SDT. If you haven't got to the bottom of that, it would be useful if you could post the relevant XML pre- and post- "removal".